# Writing strcat (string concatenate) in C

Tags: c, beginner, strings

```
char *cat_string(char *to_cat, char *destination) {
  char *copy = destination;
  while (*copy != '\0') {
    *copy++;
  }
  while (*to_cat != '\0') {
    *copy++ = *to_cat++;
  }
  *copy = '\0';
  return destination;
}
```

I would like to know if this is an efficient and effective way of writing this function. It seems silly to have to iterate through the whole array just to find the `\0` character.

Also, should I be returning the pointer to the destination? What's the best practice there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You renamed `strcat()` to `cat_string()`, so I suppose it's fitting that you reversed the traditional order of the parameters as well.  ☺

I would make three changes:

- Changing the first argument to `const` helps prevent users notice if they call the function with the parameters swapped (but doesn't prevent it in all cases).
- You have a stray pointer dereference.  It was misleading, but luckily harmless.  (In the first `while` loop, you just want to advance the `copy` pointer.  You don't care about what value it points to as you advance; you only care when you check for the <kbd>NUL</kbd> terminator.)
- <del>You can remove a statement just by changing the loop structure.</del>
  **Edit (Rev 3):** Previous recommendation was buggy, and has been retracted.  Credit to @MarcvanLeeuwen.

To answer your questions…

- The only way to find out where to start appending is to walk the entire `destination` string to locate where it ends.  That's just how C-style strings work.
- Yes, returning `destination` seems appropriate.  It's analogous to what `strcat()` does.

One final note: two spaces for indentation is too stingy, in my opinion.  It's insufficient for readability, and it also encourages inappropriately deep nesting (which would be a symptom of poorly organized code).

```
char *cat_string(const char *to_cat, char *destination) {
    char *copy = destination;
    while (*copy != '\0') {
        copy++;                 /* Removed superfluous dereference. */
    }
    …
}
```

Comment: This "improvement" breaks the correct original. Changing `while` to `do`-`while` only changes the start of the loop, not the end: with post-increment in the assignment, the (second while) condition still tests a character yet to be copied, and most of the time the terminating null character of `to_cat` is not copied to `destination`, which then remains unterminated. A null character only gets copied in case `to_cat` originally pointed to a null character (zero length concatenation), but then the loop continues until (if lucky) finding a second null character.

Comment: the real strcpy is `while(*copy++=*to_cat++);` which will end after the final \0

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Are you sure?

Comment: @200_success Of course I am sure. In your final do-while loop, you copy a character from `*do_cat++`, then because of the post-increment the `*to_cat` tested in the "while" condition is the next character, not yet copied; if it is found to be null it will not have been copied. Compare this to the solution cited by rachet freak, which copies a character and then tests the *same* character for being null. It could somewhat more explicitly be written `while((*copy++=*to_cat**)!='\0') {}`

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I stand corrected! Thank you for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 4):

1 major issue: undefined behavior when the target doesn't have enough space to hold it all and no way to prevent it with the parameters you ask for

```
char *cat_string(char *to_cat, char *destination, size_t dest_size) {
    char *copy = destination;
    copy[dest_size-1]=0;//ensure 0 termination
    while (*copy != '\0') {
        copy++;
    }
    char* end_buffer = destination+dest_size-1;
    while (*to_cat != '\0' && to_cat!=end_buffer) {
        *copy++ = *to_cat++;
    }
    *copy = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

this changes the semantics a bit but ensures that the buffer doesn't overflow

Comment: In other words, you recommend implementing `strncat()` instead of `strcat()`.

Comment: @200_success `strncat` isn't a safe strcat: strncat appends the first n bytes of source, but does nothing to avoid overflowing destination. You may be thinking of [strcat_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx) or similar.

Comment: @ChrisW You're right! I hadn't even heard of `strcat_s()` — it seems to be a Windows-only thing.

Comment: @200_success The equivalent on Unix seems to be [strlcat](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlcpy/). And maybe there's a version of [strcat_s defined in C11](http://blog.smartbear.com/codereviewer/c11-a-new-c-standard-aiming-at-safer-programming/).